# How to describe a three dimensional range.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the function $\mathbf{f}:\mathbf{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbf{R}^3$ given by $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{x}$, where $A=\begin{bmatrix}
         2 & -1 \\
         5 &  0 \\
        -6 &  3
      \end{bmatrix}$ and the vector $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbf{R}^2$ is written as the $2\times1$ column matrix $\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2
      \end{bmatrix}$. Describe the range of $\mathbf{f}$.

Clearly, $$
\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\begin{bmatrix}
               2 & -1 \\
               5 &  0 \\
              -6 &  3
            \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
              x_1 \\
              x_2
            \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
               2x_1 - x_2  \\
               5x_1        \\
              -6x_1 + 3x_2
            \end{bmatrix}.
$$ However, I am uncertain as to how to "describe" the range of $\mathbf{f}$. Do I describe each component individually?

Comment: In such cases it is best to describe the range as the set {$(x,y,z) |$.. conditions on x,y and z}.  In this particular case, can x,y, and z take all the values freely or are there any constraints ?. You can reduce the equation to RREF for simplicity.

Comment: @Shailesh Thanks for clarifying that I am along the right path. I tried to do this, but I am unfamiliar with the nuances of set builder notation. I know that $z=-3x$, but I am unsure of how to describe the relation between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You can write t for x. and -3t for z. Here t is the free variable. So you can write (t, y. -3t) where both t and y can take any real value. If you are OK with this, please accept the answer

Comment: You could also say it's the [*span*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) of the columns of the matrix $A$, and is consequently a plane (two-dimensional subspace) in $\Bbb R^3$. There are lots of ways to "describe" your set :)

Comment: @pjs36  Of course. I was only trying to keep it as simple as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :

In such cases it is best to describe the range as the set {$(x,y,z) |$.. conditions on x,y and z}.  In this particular case, can x,y, and z take all the values freely or are there any constraints ? . When you reduce the equation to RREF. you will probably see one constraint. Express it in terms of a free variable.